# Self-adjoint operator and difference of self-adjoint operator

Tags: operator-theory

I have the following question regarding self-adjoint operators and I am not quite sure about its answer. Let  $A_{n}: \operatorname{Dom}(A_{n})\subset H \rightarrow H$ be a symmetric operator densely defined on a Hilbert space $H$ that has some self-adjoint extension due to the so called Von Neumann theorem.  Consider another operator   $B_{c}: \operatorname{Dom}(B_{c}) \subset H \rightarrow H$, also a symmetric operator densely defined on a Hilbert space $H$ which also has some self-adjoint extension, again due to Von Neumann theorem. In both cases, the dimension of the deficiency spaces  is $n_{+}=n_{-}=1$. On the other hand, we can also write  $B_{c}=A_{n}+ \delta B_{c}$ or equivalently, $\delta B_{c}=B_{c}-A_{n}$. I know that in principle  $\delta B_{c}$ does not necessarily have a self-adjoint extension. Questions that I am interested in :

1. How can I prove that  $\delta B_{c}$ is not self-adjoint?
   Or, what are the conditions for it to be self-adjoint?
2. Let us suppose that $\delta B_{c} \phi=0$ with $\phi \in \operatorname{Dom} (B_{c})$. Can I conclude that the spectrum of the operator $B_{c}$ must be equal to the spectrum of $A_{n}$?

So, in the end, both problems are equivalent. Is this correct?